# Transform Rotation into location problem

Tags: constraints

I have a gear and it needs to rotate two full turns (720 degrees) to open a door which should move up for a length of three blender units. The transform works for about 180 degrees then the door falls back to the start point.
There is no difference if I'm addressing the transform Rotation Constraint to the gear or if I'm using 'the door Open Empty' and rotating that object.

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add driver to the location property with right-clicking:

[image]

Setup the driver like this:

[image]

Now the Empty's Z rotation controls the object location.

Comment: Thx for answering. I have tried to do what you suggested but as I'm pretty new there I run into problems.a) where to add the driver? I tried to add it to the door. So I clicked to the location property of the door (which should change its location) and added a single driver. But where to find the added driver?  The Z coordinate changes its color to pink, nothing ele I could not find the drivers properties anywhere. Additional : The door open Empty rotates  along the Y axis . So is there any change in the above code?

Comment: @JonnyPoet You can find drivers in Graph Editor > Mode: Drivers (its F-Curve normally) > open properties panel (N) > select driven channel on left, edit on right. If you want the Y axis then edit the Path for property to :`rotation_euler.y`

Comment: @JonnyPoet If you are new to blender it's best to watch some video-tutorials for the basics, it's harder to explain in text, easier to watch

Comment: I have already watched all the videos from Neal Hirsig chapter 1 to 12 but there is nothing about drivers and while it looks very clear in his video, in truth the Copy Rotation Constrain as well as the Transform Constrain do not work properly. But I'll look to find some videos about drivers.  BTW Does anyone know in which language this constraints are written? I want to have a look on the code, its maybe an easy small problem. IMHO Mathematical it seems to be a problem of polar coordinate quadrants calculation. I'm a C# programmer and would like to help when needed.

Comment: @JonnyPoet Constraints and also modifiers are C++, Blender itself is mix between C and C++ with addons and some UI being python. The code should be online and patchable. You can submit a patch here: https://developer.blender.org/ You can also join the blender IRC channel and ask devs if the behavior is intentional or not. I agree that blender needs to improve in lots of areas..

Comment: Thx a lot for this information. I'll have a look to get IRC connection to the developers team. BTW I have found a easy attempt now. I changed the  Transform constraint to the 'Open door Empty' object properties which is turning the gears and as a target I have  chosen the door and instead of using Y rotation transformed to Door location now I'm transforming door location into the Y rotation of the gears and this works without any troubles, But I 'll also try your suggestion, because it will be very helpful to learn more about 'how to do things' Thx a lot again

Comment: I first had to change the user preverences to allow ' auto execution. I tried your code it works great. I have changed '3*180* rot / pi /  720 to 3*rot / pi / 4 and its the same because 180 / 720 = 1/4  But your formula has helped to understand the transformation  formula now